# Hibernate Criteria Query without Relationship Between Entities

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I have two tables:

```
A (x, y, z, date1, date2)
B (t, date1, date2)
```

I want to execute a query like this:

```
SELECT A.x, A.y, A.z, A.date1
FROM   A, B 
WHERE  A.date1 < B.date1 
AND   (A.date2 is null or A.date2 <= B.date2 )
ORDER BY A.x DESC;
```

How can I do that using Hibernate Criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String           dateIdValue   = "...";
Class<?>         mainClass     = A.class;
Class<?>         dateClass     = B.class;

String           colDate1      = "date1";
String           colDate2      = "date2";
String           colDateId     = "id";

Property         date1Prop     = Property.forName(colDate1);
Property         date2Prop     = Property.forName(colDate2);

DetachedCriteria date1Criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(dateClass)
                                                 .setProjection(date1Prop)
                                                 .add(Restrictions.eq(colDateId, dateIdValue));
DetachedCriteria date2Criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(dateClass)
                                                 .setProjection(date2Prop)
                                                 .add(Restrictions.eq(colDateId, dateIdValue));

Criteria         criteria      = getSession().createCriteria(mainClass)
                                .add(date1Prop.lt(date1Criteria))
                                .add(Restrictions.or(date2Prop.isNull(), date2Prop.le(date2Criteria)))
                                .addOrder(Order.desc("x"));

/*
    SELECT A.*
    FROM   A, P
    WHERE  A.date1 < P.date1
    AND   (A.date2 is null or A.date2 <= P.date2 )
    ORDER BY A.x DESC;
 */
```

Comment: could you explain what is `colDateId` and `dateIdValue` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use subqueries. Something like this.

```
   select a,b,c,date3
       from A
       where date3 is null or 
       date3 < (select p.date1 from P p) 
       order by a desc;
```

HOWEVER! If you do not have mapped relationships between entities this is not what Hibernate is designed for and it is probably better to be using SQL directly.

Comment: I dont want to write sql or hql or jpql. I want to get results with   using Criteria API.

Comment: @mmdemirbas has done something similar to my suggestion in Criteria API. Although if this query is a valid piece of business your domain mapping should allow it.